# scan.next() not working inside a loop

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

I'm working on a program to play the game of Go Fish.  Everything works except for the `scan.next()` after looping through once.

Well, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.  Here's the code:

```
System.out.println(compHand.showHand());       

while (!(deck.isEmpty())) {
    y = 0;

    while (x == 1) {             

        System.out.println("\nYour hand:" + userHand.showHand()+ "\nYour turn. What number do you want to match?");
        guess = scan.next();
        if (compHand.checkHand(guess)) {
            System.out.println("Darn...here you go.");
            userHand.removeNum(guess);
            compHand.removeNum(guess);
            userHand.showHand();
            uP++;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Nope! Type '1' to go fish!");
            y = scan.nextInt();
            if (y == 1) {
                userHand.goFish();
                System.out.println(userHand.showHand()); 
            }
            y = 0;
        }

        guess = "";
        x--;
    }

    while (x == 0) {
        System.out.println("Do you have any " + compHand.ask() + "s?");
        ans = scan.next();
            if (!(ans.contains("go"))) {
                System.out.println("Yay!");
                userHand.removeNum(ans);
                compHand.removeNum(ans);
                cP++;
                x++;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Aww...darn.");
                compHand.goFish();
                x++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Computer's points so far: " + cP + "\nYour points so far: " + uP + "\n");
    }        
}
```

So the first time it loops through to do the user's hand, it works.  Then it works for the computer's turn, but if the computer has to go fish. When it loops back up to the user's hand it skips the `guess = scan.next();`.
I don't know what to do...

Comment: Under what circumstances does the `scan.next()` fail? What is different to when it succeeds?

Comment: Just an FYI -- I reformatted your code because you should choose one indentation/bracket style and stick to it instead of using two different styles.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to step through your code and see exactly what lines are being executed where?  It really helps with figuring out these types of issues.  Additionally, is the the "your hand..." text being printed out when this skip occurs?  If not, then most likely it's because `x != 1` when the loop condition is evaluated.

Answer (score -1):

The problems comes from the buffer. You have to **free** it. To do so, put a scan.nextLine() **just before the closing bracket** of the loop and it will free the buffer. You will be able then to enter an input.

Comment: So the method `removeNum` can handle both, `String` and `int`? How do you know that?

Comment: I do not understand your question. the scan.nextLine() that i suggested you add has to be added in order to free the buffer.

Comment: So then explain please, why OP should replace `next()` with `nextInt()`? And `nextLine()` is only necessary, because you suggested to use `nextInt()`.

Comment: I understand now. I wanted him to replace it because the way he named his variables and the text he prints indicate that he is waiting for a number. And if he needs a String, he could always use the String.valueOf(int i).

Comment: *She
And yes, sometimes it's a number, but it could also be "J" "Q" or "K" for the face cards, or an "A" for an ace.  Yes, I need a string.  I have the code to then change it to an int as needed, but for putting it into the code I need a string.
It's a very odd problem.

Comment: So if you want a String, why don't you simply use a nextLine instead of next. Or it does not change anything ?

Comment: Whenever I tried to do a nextLine it just jumps over it on the first run entirely for some reason.

Comment: @Normaldesign Using `nextLine()` instead of `next()` is a _very_ bad idea if OP uses `nextInt()` in the code.

Comment: No! I meant forgetting totally the nextInt because of the story of the cards and using instead of next the nextLine ...

Comment: I knew that was what you meant... I tried nextLine() and instead of it messing up on the second loop, it messed up on the first loop. It won't even read it in.

Comment: @Tom I don't used nextInt() in the code, and in response to your first question, the method removeNum is a method I wrote in an adjoining class that goes with this code, it changes it from a String to an Int and removes it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is a matter of the buffer that does not free itself. Could you put a nextLine() at the end of the loop, outside of any block, just before the last closing bracket of the loop and tell me if it changes something. You sure have to keep the guess = scan.next now.

Comment: @Holly You do not? And what is this: `y = scan.nextInt();`? And can you please edit your question a bit? It is currently unclear what you mean with *"When it loops back up to the user's hand it skips the guess = scan.next();."*. Won't the system let you enter something? Or what happens? Can you provide a simple input and output?

Comment: @Tom, It will not let me enter something through the second looping for guess = scan.next().

Comment: @Normaldesign I will try and get back to you in a minute.

Comment: No problem. I'll edit my previous answer in order to put the right one so other people can benefit from it. Do not forget please to accept the answer once I've edited (and why not vote for it :p)

Comment: And what happens instead? Do you get an exception? Does the code still use your first input?

Comment: @Normaldesign *"so other people can benefit from it."* It is a good idea, but I guess no one will ever know, that he has the same problem as Holly had. The only reason a `next()` call "skips" is that she entered whitespaces somewhere*. And since she never showed us what she enters to the console, it is unlikely that someone else has the same problem.  (*) Or she manipulated the `Scanner` instance to use different delimiters. Who knows.

Comment: It is a common error. It happens often. Do not worry about that. And it is not because of a white space, not at all. It is because of line retrun, or known in the programming word as the special char '\n'. I'll repeat my message so she can see it : 
 
No problem. I'll edit my previous answer in order to put the right one so other people can benefit from it. Do not forget please to accept the answer once I've edited (and why not vote for it :p)